# How do I remove a metasploit infection?

Tags: malware, metasploit

My brother in law sent me a link in a Facebook PM for dummy me to click on. I did, nothing happened, I thought nothing of it. Well he told my husband since I clicked on it he can now hack my Facebook account. I didn't think he could, I have my account set at high security.

After a bit of search on the link, I found out what it is, now I want to kill him!

How do I undo my click on the link and remove metasploit infection if there is one? He sent me this...

```
$ chmod +r /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/ui/config/database.yml
$ sudo msfconsole
```

Comment: Those commands launch the metasploit program.

Comment: Can you post a copy of the link itself? I'm interested to see how the exploit is supposed to be able to execute those lines...

Comment: No once I clicked on it, it became un clickable.

Comment: Your brother in law is either very inept or very skilled at yanking your chain :)

Comment: Well he does have a computer business "Umbram Computer Services", he is a prankster but I don't trust him!

Answer (score 1):

In order for those commands to work, you would need to have metasploit already installed. Do you? Are you on Windows\Linux\Mac?

Just launching the program isn't a risk. Metasploit helps you infect other machines and isn't a virus itself.

Without more info, it looks like your brother is playing with you.

Comment: I'm on windows 8, I don't have it installed, so he can't really do anything with it?

Comment: those commands will not work on Windows